# How to use dash (-) with unix commands correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have just noticed that commands:

```
ps -T
```

and

```
ps T
```

give different results. For instance:

[image: ps -T]

[image: ps T]

I mean lines 2 and 3 of second output. 
Could someone please explain what happens here and how the dash really works in such commands (to be honest I thought options that didn't require an argument could be given without a dash).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dash is nothing special. Each (and I really mean each) program decides on its own how to interpret its arguments, including the dash. `ps` is a bit unconventional in this manner (just like many other old tools, for instance `tar`). Usually I don't recommend this as an answer, but it seems like you have to consult `man ps`.

Comment: In this case, `ps` accepts Unix style options (require a dash) and BSD style options (no dash)... and also GNU long option (double dash).

Comment: Note that "how do I use UNIX tools?" questions are generally better suited to [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/); Stack Overflow is specifically for questions *unique to* software development.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Right, I forgot these pages, next time I will use them, thanks :)

Comment: (btw, the [POSIX utility argument syntax specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) _does_ give guidelines about how dashes are _usually_ supposed to work in UNIX command-line tools, but specific tools can have special cases; the guidelines are just that -- but that said, see the section 12.2 at the bottom of the above link; the 14 guidelines there set out how things are _generally_ supposed to work).

Comment: Try `man ps` for help on options. `T` shows processes associated with your terminal. `-T` shows threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happens here

From [`man ps`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ps.1) with `ps` from `procps`:

> This version of ps accepts several kinds of options:
>
> 1   UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a
> dash.
> 2.   BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used
> with a dash.
> 3.   GNU long options, which are preceded by two
> dashes.

> T      Select all processes associated with this terminal.

> -T     Show threads, possibly with SPID column.

Two options with different meaning.

> how the dash really works in such commands

Dash represents literally itself. `-` is a `-`, the character `-`. Then the program has logic, if the string that represents the argument passed to the program starts with a `-` character, then the logic of that program is different, then when the argument does not start with `-`.

> o be honest I thought options that didn't require an argument could be given without a dash

Each and every program has it's own unique semantics and parsing. While there are conventions and standards and options starting with a leading `-` are the (almost) universal standard, there are exceptions.  (For example, "traditional" `tar` command syntax recognizes options without a `-`.)

> How to use dash (-) with unix commands correctly?

Consult that "command" that you want to run, as it depends on that command how it parses it's arguments.